# Positions of squares and diamonds

Tags: knowledge, visual

**Based on the eight figures below determine what the last figure will look like (replace the question marks). Explain why.**

---

```
* * *     * * ◇     * * *     * * *     * □ *     * * *     ◇ * *     * * *     ? ? ?
□   *     *   *     *   □     *   *     □   *     □   *     □   *     □   □     ?   ?
* * ◇     * □ *     ◇ * *     ◇ □ *     * * *     ◇ * *     * * *     * * *     ? ? ?
```

Comment: The use of `◇` symbols makes the question very hard to read, since (for me, at least) they're a non-standard width in an otherwise fixed-width font.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Hm I didn't notice this using computer but when I use my phone I see it doesn't look the way I intended.

Comment: Yeah, it's probably a mobile-ish issue; I'm on a Chromebook. Frustrating.

Comment: Why don't you just write 'S' and 'D' instead?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The question mark should be replaced by

> ```
>  * * ◇
>  *   *
>  * □ *
> ```

which resembles

> letter **E** in [flag semaphore](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_semaphore).

Because,

> when the images are interpreted as flag semaphore, it spells **SEMAPHORE** itself.

Comment: This is correct, nice job!